# File mapping corruption?

Tags: terminal, finder

Text editor (BBedit) in macOS Monterey is experiencing a curious issue in opening files.

Context: a folder with the same name/directory had existed previously, and was used for generating an application. At some point it was destroyed but **may** have had a terminal session running on that directory.

Subsequently, that directory was recreated and, for good measure, duplicated.

At present two directories exist `directory_name` and a duplicate `directory_name copy`.

Opening a file in the `copy` directory via double-click would open the file of the non-copy directory; only dragging the file from the copy directory over the application icon would open the proper file.

Additionally, the application is behaving in ways that allude to code that was *probably* in place from the original(deleted) directory, messing matters up royally.  Even after a system re-start.

Can this be cleaned up and if so, how?  Is the better course to start with new directory name and keep that directory off limits?

Comment: Presumably, the terminal session has now finished? You're sure that the copy (or files inside) aren't a link or alias? How did a folder 'generate an app'? Have you run First Aid over the disk? What type of disk is it? What model of Mac? I would try a completely different name, and see if the behaviour persists.